# Codigniter htaccess error 404 at production

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, codeigniter, mod-rewrite

i am very begainer to server technologies.i know this question asked too many times but i really don't get it run.
it runs with 
domain.com/2.0/index.php/test
but when you remove index.php it throws

> The requested URL /2.0/test was not found on this server.
>   Apache/2.2.15 (CentOS) Server at domain.com port 443

**my project stucture**
[image]
 - 

Public_html
    
--2.0(this is my project folder where ci can be located.it has sys,app,.htaccess)
    
--.htaccess

**My domain** 
https://domain.com/2.0/

**about the problem**
i have two htaccess one at root mention above one is inside 2.0 folder
and the strange thing is what ever i write in the htaccess file it never effect anything

public_html/.htaccess

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

public_html/2.0/.htaccess

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
```

my httpd.conf

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerAdmin info@domain.com
    DocumentRoot /home/natural/public_html
    ServerName api01.domain.net
    ErrorLog /var/log/httpd/error_log
    CustomLog /var/log/access_log common

    SSLEngine on
    SSLCertificateFile /home/natural/api01.domain.net.crt
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /home/natural/api01.domoin.key

    <Directory />
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        Allow from all
        AllowOverride None
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

i search alot and follow all the answers by Stack overflow but no luck.

Comment: Please update the question to include the content of those .htaccess files. The answer probably would be to add rewrite condition to the one in the root to exclude everything under 2.0 folder. Or even merge two files into one.

Comment: i updated the question added my two htaccess

Comment: add image of your folder structure

Comment: @AbdulManan is your project is in 2.0 ? add clear image with application folder and all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume 2.0 is the new version of the site. It looks like `/2.0/.htaccess` is written as though it expects to be in the root folder. Try adding `RewriteBase /2.0/` after engine on. You can remove it later when you replace the contents of the root folder with that of `2.0`'s.

The main problem is your `# Handle Front Controller...` rule. It'll capture any virtual URLs before they ever get to the `2.0` folder. Try changing it to this:

```
RewriteRule ^(?!2\.0(?:/|$)) index.php [L]
```

That will exclude the `2.0` folder from the current site's virtual URLs.

You do still need `AllowOverride all` as recommended by the other answer, and the directory should be the same as your `DocumentRoot`, not `/`.

Comment: first thing is 2.0 is not new version its something else root will hold website 2.0 will hold api

Comment: you mean to change like this 
``# Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^(?!2\.0(?:/|$)) index.php [L]``

Comment: Yes, I meant change that one line, not remove others.

Answer (score 2):

The directive "AllowOverride None" in httpd.conf will disable parsing of the .htaccess file within the directories specified (in this case /) -- Can you confirm that either of your .htaccess files are in fact being parsed?

If not, does modifying the Directory subsection within your httpd.conf file to:

```
<Directory />
Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
Allow from all
AllowOverride All
</Directory>
```

Solve the issue?

For more information: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#allowoverride

Comment: thanks for nice replay i change none to ALL but no Luck

Answer (score 1):

Add this code inside root->.htaccess file

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|resources|robots\.txt)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^(?!2\.0(?:/|$)) index.php [L]
```